# Jslink / CSR Field Override Issues

Tags: javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering

I'm experiencing issues with the JSLink Override specifically for individual fields.

When attached to items, headers and footers I have no problem, but the field functions don't fire at all. Code below. I may be overlooking something ~ the debugger at the beginning of the function doesn't fire.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = 
    {
        'Title': { 'View': overrideField }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}     
)();

function overrideField(ctx){
    debugger
    return "<div class='fellowID'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: does JavaScript load successfully at all? have you missed any syntax errors? does anything look wrong in the console output? does a simple breakpoint work with developer tools active?

Comment: Yep. Js Loads. Header, footer & item loads - fields doesn't.

Comment: Always use [Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar) for CSR, you are now missing all the boilerplate code that takes care of MDS, and it will give you the boilerplate code for Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal field name was `LinkTitleNoMenu`.